# How to integrate Jmeter result with Elasticsearch & Grafana via Docker?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, jmeter, dockerfile, grafana

I am going to migrate the Jmeter from UI to Docker-based system.

Previously, we create backend listener manually on UI to input the Elasticsearch/influx details to ship the result to it. Now how would I do when we run it with docker container and then connect the Elasticsearch to Grafana.

How we connect the three tools via single Dockerfile to get the runtime test result and monitor it?

Thanks

Comment: These are very resourceful articles [JMeter – Centralized Logging Solution in Distributed Testing using ElasticSearch + Beats + Kibana](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-centralized-logging-solution-in-distributed-testing-using-elasticsearch-beats-kibana/), [JMeter – Distributed Load Testing using Docker](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-distributed-load-testing-using-docker/), [JMeter – Scaling out load generators using Docker Compose in distributed load testing](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-scaling-out-load-servers-using-docker-compose-in-distributed-load-testing/)

Comment: Thanks, will try but I need to just pass the jmx file via jenkins, and everything should run at background(jmeter result->influxdb->grafana) via docker

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers concept is to only run one thing in one container. So you would need three container to do that.
Then you publish the ports you need and connect to them normally.